# Printing binary plus/negation operators in front of untested signed variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, siunitx, pgfmath

Suppose I have two macros `\numa` and `\numb` into which I imported values out of some external calculations.

I would like to use them in equations such that the binary plus/negation operators should always be printed in front of them **without having to test their signs** beforehand. In other words, I need to have the correct binary plus/negation sign **automatically chosen and printed** based on their signs.

For the MWE below, I would like to know

1- how to convert the plus sign of `\num[explicit-sign=+]` into a binary one in case (a) to have the proper spacing around it as in cases (b) and (c)

2- why case (d) of `\pgfmathifthenelse` fails to have the plus sign printed

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,tikz}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
    \def\numa{5}
    \def\numb{-3}
    (a) $1 \num[explicit-sign=+]\numa \num{\numb}$\\
    (b) $1 \ifnum\numa>0+\fi \numa \numb$\\
    (c) $1 \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\numa>0,"+",)}\pgfmathresult \numa \numb$\\
    (d) $1 \pgfmathifthenelse{\numa>0}{"+"}{} \numa  \numb$
\end{document}
```

Comment: One way to reduce the spacing around `+` is to write `{+}`, which changes what type of symbol it is.

Comment: @Davislor Actually, I need the spacing in (a) to be as big as that of (b) and (c)

Comment: Instead of testing whether it is bigger than 0 you should probably test whether it's not smaller than 0, or else you could get `10 - 3` instead of `1 + 0 - 3`. Also, why don't you define your own macro that simply does what your (b) does and use that one where you want to sum over your results (so `\newcommand\mysummand[1]{\unless\ifnum#1<0 +\fi#1}` and then use `\mysummand\numa` and `\mysummand\numb`)?

Comment: @Skillmon My problem is already solved using approaches (b) and (c). However, I need to figure out how to handle it using `\num` and `\pgfmathifthenelse`. For the testing `\ifnum <0`, I was lazy to make it that way since I always am sure that I won't get zero.

Comment: I think the edited title is misleading -- you really want a binary plus (not a unary) when addition is indicated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's my bad. I corrected my question

Comment: `\pgfmathifthenelse` writes the result to `\pgfmathresult`, as the other `pgfmath`-macros do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advice of adding `\mathbin` is the essential point, but combining the parsing requirements needs some care.  Below I have defined an `\snum` macro to do this for you.  It takes the same optional arguments as `\num`, processes the sign using `pgfmath` and prints out the absolute part of the number using `siunitx`, subverting the mechanism for bracketing negative numbers.  This to avoid the different formatting that would come from instead using `pgfmath` (in the default situation `\pgfmathabs{5}\pgfmathresult` prints `5.0`).

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,tikz}

\newcommand{\snum}[2][]{\pgfmathifthenelse{#2 >=0}{"+"}{"-"}%
\mathbin{\pgfmathresult}%
\num[#1,bracket-negative-numbers,close-bracket={},open-bracket={}]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\def\numa{5}
\def\numb{-3}

(a) $1 \snum{\numa} \snum{\numb}$

(b) $1 \ifnum\numa>0+\fi \numa \numb$

(c) $1 \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\numa>=0,"+",)}\pgfmathresult \numa \numb$

(d) $1 \pgfmathifthenelse{\numa>=0}{"\mathbin{+}"}{}\pgfmathresult \numa
\numb$

\end{document}
```

Note: case (b) is included only for comparison with the original question, it works only on integers, whereas the other case will also work on decimals.

## Update

For newer versions of `siunitx` the above code can be adapted as below, but given one has to go into expl syntax, one is better off using the solution of egreg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600885/15925

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\snum}{O{} m}{
\tl_set:Nn \l__siunitx_number_bracket_open_tl { }
\tl_set:Nn \l__siunitx_number_bracket_close_tl { }
\ensuremath{\pgfmathifthenelse{#2 >=0}{"+"}{"-"}%
\mathbin{\pgfmathresult}%
\num[#1,bracket-negative-numbers]{#2}}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\numa{5}
\def\numb{-3}

(a) $1 \snum{\numa} \snum{\numb}$

(b) $1 \ifnum\numa>0+\fi \numa \numb$

(c) $1 \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\numa>=0,"+",)}\pgfmathresult \numa \numb$

(d) $1 \pgfmathifthenelse{\numa>=0}{"\mathbin{+}"}{}\pgfmathresult \numa
\numb$

With decimals

\def\numa{5.2}
\def\numb{-3.1}

(1) $1.2 \snum{\numa} \snum{\numb}$

(2) \snum{\numa} and \snum{\numb} in text

\end{document}
```

Comment: When using fractions as in `\def\numa{5.65}`, I get this error `Missing = inserted for \ifnum. (b) $1 \ifnum\numa`.  `I was expecting to see <, =, or >. Didn't.` `A number should have been here; I inserted 0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up weird error in the index to The TeXbook.)`

Comment: @Diaa Thank you.  `\ifnum` is only for integers.  It is included because the OP wanted the same formatting as that case gives.

Comment: Is it possible to have a text-mode version of `snum`? Also, how should this answer be changed to work with siunitx version 3 after removing `close-bracket` and `open-bracket` options?

Comment: @Diaa I'll take a look at the new syntax, but there is not a direct translation.  To use in text just enclose the definition in `\ensuremath`

Answer (score 2):

To make an atom match the spacing in (B) and (C), wrap it in `\mathbin`.   For example:

```
\( a \textnormal{+} b \) versus \( a \mathbin{\textnormal{+}} b \)
```

[image: Computer modern sample]

The plus sign is typeset as a binary operator (`\mathbin`), and you were using an ordinary atom (`\mathord`).

A unary plus that should have no extra spacing is `\mathord{+}` or just `{+}`.

Comment: Would you please show how the unary operators can be robustly added for the first and last case in my MWE to have the proper spacing you referred in your answer?

Comment: @Diaa I’m not sure exactly what spacing you want.

Comment: Around the unary plus/minus signs as you did using \mathbin knowing that I don't actually know the sign or the value of the external numbers stored in the macros.

Comment: @Diaa A unary plus or minus would be `\mathord{+}` or just `{+}`.

Comment: Thanks to @barbara comment, I realized that my question title/description is misleading and unclear. Kindly, check again my question after my edits.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler implementation with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\snum}{O{}m}
 {
  \mathbin
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { #2 >= 0 }
     { + }
     { - }
   }
  \num[#1]{ \fp_eval:n { abs(#2) } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\numa{5}
\def\numb{-3}

$1 \snum{\numa} \snum{\numb}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks forthe help. Is it possible to use it in text mode? I am sorry to ask but I am away from PC.

Comment: @Diaa why text mode for math?

Comment: You are right. There is something that can't be solved yet: I need the spacing around the negative sign in the second line to be as wide as that of the first line here `$1 \snum{\numa} \snum{\numb}$\\
 $\snum{\numb}$` https://i.ibb.co/4tjL275/image.png. So, the plus or negative signs are always treated as binary regardless there are other arguments or not.

Comment: `\vphantom{}` makes the minus sign binary but ,undesirably, shifts the second line a bit to the right `$1 \snum{\numa} \snum{\numb}$\\ $\vphantom{}\snum{\numb}$`. https://i.ibb.co/VYZX44k/image.png So, I just need the wide spacing around it on one side (of the number) wihtout having to use extra commands (e.g. `\vphantom`) if possible.